# How to extract url from GET http request

Tags: python, http

so I have the data from a HTTP GET request in the following way:

```
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
etc etc
```

I would like extract the url next to GET and store it in a variable..looked through some stuff on the net but can't find a solid way of doing it. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: (1) That’s not a valid HTTP request; (2) Have you tried basic string manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp :

```
import re

url_pattern = re.compile("^GET (.*)[ ].*")
line = "GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1"
url = url_pattern.match(line).group(1)
```

If you are sure there is never a space in URL :-D